# Как в django админке отфильтровать значения в dropdown inlines?

Tags: django, django-admin

Имеем: Товары, Категории товаров, для каждой категории товаров заданы свои свойства. В Django админке при редактировании товара в `inlines` задаем значения для каждого свойства товара. Как отфильтровать список свойств товара в `inlines` dropdown по выбранной в товаре категории?

**models.py**

```
class Product(OrderingBaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name"),
        default="",
        max_length=250,
    )

    category = TreeForeignKey(
        "Category",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="categories",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_("Category"),
    )

    ...

class Category(MPTTModel, OrderingBaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name"),
        default="",
        max_length=250,
    )

    ...

class CategoryProperty(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Name"),
        default="",
        max_length=50,
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        "Category",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="categories_property",
        verbose_name=_("Category"),
    )
    ...

class ProductProperty(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        "Product",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = "properties_product",
        verbose_name = _("Product"),
    )
    category_property = models.ForeignKey(
        "CategoryProperty",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name = "category_property",
        verbose_name = _("Property"),
    )
    value = models.CharField(
        _("Value"),
        default = "",
        max_length = 10,
    )
    ...
```

**admin.py**

```
class ProductPropertyInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductPropertyInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["category_property"].queryset = CategoryProperty.objects.filter(category__id = ??? Что тут прописать ???)

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProductPropertyInline,]
    ...
```